# SQL: Selecting associated values

Tags: sql

I have a database with a EMPLOYEES table that has the following columns:

```
(EmpID    char(4) unique Not null,
 Ename    varchar(10),
 Job      varchar(9),
 MGR      char(4),
 Hiredate date,
 Salary   decimal(7,2),
 Comm     decimal(7,2),
 DeptNo   char(2) not null,
     Primary key(EmpID),
     Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));
```

With a sample INSERT:

```
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
```

I cannot figure out how to list all employees and their managers by manager name.  I do not know how to display a manager name, just the number.

Comment: Join the table to itself, giving each instance a different alias so you can refer to `employee.Ename` and `manager.Ename` even though both `employee` and `manager` are the same `EMPLOYEES` table.

Comment: `SELECT  manager.Ename as 'Manager Name', e.Ename as 'Employee Name'
From Employees e, EMPLOYEES manager
Join EMPLOYEES
on Employees.Ename = manager.ENAME;`

I tried the above, but with incorrect results.  I joined the tables and attempted to display the the aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query from your comment is wrong, as it performs the `JOIN` on the Ename.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  manager.Ename as 'Manager Name'
  , e.Ename as 'Employee Name' 
FROM 
  Employees e
  JOIN Employees manager on e.MGR = manager.EmpID;
```

Your original query joined the table on the name. You should tie the MGR id to the EmpID to find the manager.